# Why Does my HttpWebRequest Return 400 Bad request?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

The following code fails with a 400 bad request exception. My network connection is good and I can go to the site but I cannot get this uri with HttpWebRequest.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://www.youtube.com/");
    try
    {
        //returns a 400 bad request... Any ideas???
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Log(ex.Message);                
    }
}
```

Comment: is it asp.net or windows form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, cast the WebRequest to an HttpWebRequest like this:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://www.youtube.com/");
```

Then, add this line of code:

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
```

Answer (score 5):

Set **UserAgent** and **Referer** in your **HttpWebRequest**:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.youtube.com/");
request.Referer = "http://www.youtube.com/"; // optional
request.UserAgent =
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; " +
    "Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; " +
    ".NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; " +
    "InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)";
try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Log(ex);
}
```

Comment: I suggest he use Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString()), so he gets the entire exception, not just the message.

Answer (score 4):

There could be many causes for this problem.  Do you have any more details about the WebException?

One cause, which I've run into before, is that you have a bad user agent string.  Some websites (google for instance) check that requests are coming from known user agents to prevent automated bots from hitting their pages.

In fact, you may want to check that the user agreement for YouTube does not preclude you from doing what you're doing.  If it does, then what you're doing may be better accomplished by going through approved channels such as web services.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've got a proxy server running, and you haven't set the Proxy property of the HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Good guess. This is internal to the proxy i'm writing.