# Why would C# HttpWebRequest return 500 error on ResponseStream, but not with PHP?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out with this problem. I've got some C# code which reads in the contents of a web page for parsing later on. The code is:

```
        private StringReader ReadInUrl(string url)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;            
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";           

            using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return new StringReader(result);
        }
```

The code works fine with most pages, but throws a 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.' with some pages. An example of a page that throws the error would be : http://www.thehut.com/blu-ray/harry-potter-collection-years-1-6/10061821.html

The thing that confuses me is that I can view the page fine using a webbrowser, and I can also grab the contents of the file using PHP fopen and fread, and then parse it in PHP.

I really need to be able to do this in C# and I'm stumped as to why it is happening. If any one could let me know why I can read in the page using PHP and not C#, and whether there is a setting in C# that could get round this issue? Any answers gratefully received!

Comment: Check out this, as you might need to set your user agent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702079/c-simple-httpwebrequest-question

Comment: You'll really need to catch the exception and read its details to know more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web site drops requests that doesn't specify a user agent. So you need to specify it. Also I would recommend you using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instead of `HttpWebRequest`, `HttpWebResponse`, `StreamReader`, `StringReader` and company:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
            string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.thehut.com/blu-ray/harry-potter-collection-years-1-6/10061821.html");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

it's kinda shorter and works.

Comment: or - request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US)";

Comment: Darin, thanks very much. This fixes the problem straight away. It was setting the user agent that solved it. Thanks also to Kirk who suggested the same fix, and to everyone else who kindly replied.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that PHP is including some header that `WebRequest` doesn't include by default - and the server is failing to handle it. I've just reproduced this myself, and it really *is* an internal server error at thehut.com. Here's the server-side exception as far as it's shown in the HTML that's returned:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
org.apache.jsp.hut.errors.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:71)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.thehut.elysium.filter.SiteFilter.forwardToErrorPage(Unknown Source)
com.thehut.elysium.filter.SiteFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
com.thehut.elysium.filter.SlowRequestFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
com.thehut.elysium.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
```

Not terribly helpful, but it does basically confirm that it's a server-side issue - and it certainly sounds suspiciously like a header which the servlet assumes will be present.

You could try making the same request from your PHP code, and see what headers it uses (using [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org)). Add those headers to the .NET `WebRequest` one at a time, and see what it needs before it starts working.