# why WebHttpRequest.ResponseUri not returning correct url in C#

Tags: .net

Here is my code for getting url from browser through "HttpWebRequest" and "HttpWebResponse".

```
{
    string link="http://g.microsoftonline.com/0BXPS00id-id/1250";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    string responseurl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(responseurl);
}
```

when i executed the above code the url return is

**"https://mocp.microsoftonline.com/Site/Error.aspx?Err=NotSupported"**

but when i manually open the link in browser it redirects to

**"https://mocp.microsoftonline.com/Site/Support.aspx"**

why the response.ResponseUri.ToString() returning wrong url?

Can you please provide solution for this?

Comment: Just open https://mocp.microsoftonline.com/Site/Error.aspx?Err=NotSupported in your browser and you'll see.

Comment: thanks,not only this link but for some other links also, the url return from HttpWebresponse is different from when we manually open the links in browser

Answer (score 0):

Through the request.UserAgent property you can act as a browser that's supported.
The following worked for me

```
string link = "http://g.microsoftonline.com/0BXPS00id-id/1250";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

string responseurl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(responseurl)
```

I'm not an expert at the UserAgent-value. I graciously snurched the above value for UserAgent from https://stackoverflow.com/a/702110/455904

Comment: Thanks, it's working for that link but i had a problem with other link even by using "request.UserAgent". 

if i use the above code for the link 
[link]"http://g.microsoftonline.com/0BXPS00id-id/1222" 

it returns 

"http://exchangeonline.pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/SelectCulture.aspx"

but when i manually open that link in browser it showing as below

"http://exchangeonline.pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/services/search/data-management-and-migration-b200025?WT.mc_id=ww_Perm_Deeplink_Office365__o365dl"

Comment: I get a 301-result on the first link which means it has been moved. After redirect it then probably makes some choices based on your browsers current cookies. You can trace these calls for instance by using IEs developer tools (F12). After that try and find out what cookie(s) seems to do the trick and fill request.CookieContainer with these.

Comment: i am not expert in catching cookies so can you provide me code for this based on your browser, then i will know better on this.

Comment: I'm no expert either but as I wrote I use Internet Explorers developer tools (press F12 to access). Select the Network tab -> click the button to begin register the calls -> visit your URL. The communication between the web server and IE will be displayed in the list below. Double click on any row, and then navigate between the various calls. The cookie tab displays what cookies are stored or accessed for each call.

Comment: finally i got. "request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;" this will gives me correct forward url(301)