# System.Net.WebException using WebRequest

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying hard  using WebRequest class to get handle URL for downloading.It works except, when i enter a link such as https://soundcloud.com/top-bollywood-songs/atif-aslam-mashup-full-song-dj (last segment extension-less) it throws System.Net.WebException and returns " The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".

```
  WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Suggestions please!!!

Comment: I found interesting info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702079/why-does-my-httpwebrequest-return-400-bad-request

Comment: I used Webclient side by side in my implementation.It doesn't support extension-less links to download.How can i get ?@RotemVaron

Comment: You just need to add the user agent

Comment: Still in this case ,its downloading me an html page rather than  music

Comment: No,WebClient doesn't requires such parameters

Comment: if you need a file resource, you can try FileWebRequest instead

Comment: That's true. How about the above case where the  `request.UserAgent` works but with no  music .

Comment: @RotemVaron   I must say if one's going to code his downloader app ,he must ensure that WebClient or WebRequest handles URL's correctly even though extension-less

Answer (score 0):

You can add the User Agent. The following is a working example:

```
protected string getHTML(string url)
{
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            // ******  Add the this line! ****//
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

            // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
            request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
            request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
            // Set credentials to use for this request.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Get the stream associated with the response.
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            string html = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            return html;
}
```

Comment: It forces me to use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebRequest`.can i get around this so that it may work regardless of http connections

Comment: @devprog, WebRequest class is an abstract class, the actual behavior of WebRequest instances at run time is determined by the descendant class returned by Create method. For more information about default values and exceptions, see the documentation for the descendant classes, such as HttpWebRequest and FileWebRequest.